# Torch Element-wise Logical Operation and/or

Tags: deep-learning, torch, elementwise-operations

I am trying to perform *logical* element-wise opertaions on tensors, but it seems "and" keyword performs logical *or*, while "or" keyword performs logical *and* :

```
    a = torch.zeros(3)
    a[1] = 1                      -- a will be [1,0,0]
    b = torch.ones(3)
    b[3] = 0                      -- b will be [1,1,0]
    c = torch.eq(a,1) and torch.eq(b,1) 
    d = torch.eq(a,1) or  torch.eq(b,1)
```

I was expecting c to become `[1,0,0]` since it would make sense to have 1 only in positions where both a **and** b are equal to 1. Also I was expecting d to become `[1,1,0]` since those are the positions where either a **or** b are equal to 1. To my surprise, the results are completely the opposite!
Any explanations?

Comment: Warning: according to the answer, this method is  absolutely incorrect for element-wise logical operations on Tensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Lua docs:

> The operator and returns its first argument if it is false; otherwise,
>   it returns its second argument. The operator or returns its first
>   argument if it is not false; otherwise, it returns its second
>   argument

In this case, that behaviour is happening just as a "coincidence". It will return the second argument (Tensor `a`) while applying the `and` operator and the first argument (Tensor `b`) while applying the `or` operator. Also, tensor `a` corresponds to the element-wise logical and while tensor `b` corresponds to the element-wise logical or.

Comment: You are right! I just figured using torch.cmax(a, b) would be equivalent to "a or b" and torch.cmin(a, b) to "a and b" (you need to make sure a and b are logical tensors; i.e. they only contain 1s and 0s)